Динамически менять ширину центрального слайда
Пишу карусель используя swiper и next.js 13, но столкнулся с проблемой что при изменение ширины активного слайда (который по середине), то данный слайд не по середине а чуть в сторону.
Использовал ResizeObserver для отслеживания изменения ширины выбранного слайда, но в данном случае слайд не перемещается плавно к центру и телепотируется. Как сделать плавную анимацию изменения ширину выбраного блока (без использования scale)?
const Carousel: React.FC = () => {
  const [swiperRef, setSwiperRef] = useState<SwiperClass>(null);
  const [clickedSlide, setClickedSlide] = useState<number>();

  const handleClickSlide = (swiper: SwiperClass) => {
    setClickedSlide(swiper.clickedIndex);
  };

  return (
    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={() => setClickedSlide(undefined)} mouseEvent="onMouseDown">
      <div className={classNames(style['swiper-container'])}>
        <div className={style['swiper-prev']}>&larr;</div>

        <Swiper
          onSwiper={setSwiperRef}
          onClick={handleClickSlide}
          direction="horizontal"
          slidesPerView="auto"
          speed={600}
          slideToClickedSlide
          centeredSlides
          resizeObserver
          freeMode
          navigation={{
            nextEl: '.' + style['swiper-next'],
            prevEl: '.' + style['swiper-prev'],
          }}
          mousewheel={{
            sensitivity: 0.5,
          }}
          modules={[Navigation, Mousewheel, Manipulation]}
        >
          {
            slides.map((slide) => {
              const active = clickedSlide == index;

              return (
                <SwiperSlide className={classNames(style['swiper-slide'], active && style['swiper-slide-active'])}>
                  <SlideComponent slide={slide} active={active} swiper={swiperRef} />
                </SwiperSlide>
              );
            })
          }
        </Swiper>

        <div className={style['swiper-next']}>  &rarr;</div>
      </div>
    </ClickAwayListener>
  );
};

SlideComponent.tsx
const SlideComponent = React.forwardRef<HTMLDivElement, MapCarouselSlideProps>(({
  job,
  className,
  active,
  swiper,
  ...props
}, ref) => {
  const slide = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => slide.current!, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!slide.current) {
      return;
    }

    const observer = new ResizeObserver(() => swiper.update());
    observer.observe(slide.current);

    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, [active]);

  return (
    <div ref={slide} className={classNames(style['slide-component'], className)} {...props} >
      text
    </div>
  );
});


CSS
.swiper-slide {
  flex-basis: 280px;
  width: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 16px;
  transition: flex-basis 500ms ease-in-out !important;
}

.swiper-slide-active {
  flex-basis: 520px;
  width: 520px;
}

В поисках решение наткнулся на вопросы в git проекта swiper:
add width to swiper-slide-active makes centeredSlides to fail

Исправил используя костыль
Добавил стиль для map-carousel-wrapper
.map-carousel-wrapper {
  align-items: flex-end;
  transition: all 300ms linear !important;
}

и ResizeObserver для каждого слайда
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!slide.current) {
      return;
    }

    const observer = new ResizeObserver(() => swiper.update());
    observer.observe(slide.current);

    return () => observer.disconnect();
  }, [active]);

